# Java stopwatch GUI program complies but does not run

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer, stopwatch

I have an assignment where I have to create a GUI stopwatch program that has a start, stop, and reset button to the timer.

So far I have a program that compiles correctly but produces the error below when I go to run the program so I'm unsure of how to correct this.

```
at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Container.java:492)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1093)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:419)
at TimerFrame.main(TimerFrame.java:30)

Process completed.
```

Any help with running my program, or any other improvements that could be made to make the program run more smoothly that would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to learning java so any help is appreciated.

I've included my code down below as well.

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TimerFrame {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      new TimerPanel();
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stopwatch GUI");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      TimerPanel panel = new TimerPanel();
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerPanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {
    private int count;
    private JButton start;
    private JButton stop;
    private JButton reset;
    private JLabel label;
    private Timer timer;
    private double time;
    private double extra = 0;

    public TimerPanel(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3));

        label = new JLabel("00.00", JLabel.CENTER);

        add(label);

        // Creating a panel (JPanel) for hte buttons to reside in
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();

        // initilizing buttons
        start = new JButton("Start");
        stop = new JButton("Stop");
        reset = new JButton("Reset");

        // adds the buttons start, stop, and reset to the panel
        buttons.add(start);
        buttons.add(stop);
        buttons.add(reset);

        // adds the panel to the frame
        add(buttons);

        // adding action listeners to the buttons
        start.addActionListener(this);
        stop.addActionListener(this);
        reset.addActionListener(this);

        // initilize timer
        timer = new Timer(0, this);
        timer.setDelay(1000);

        setBackground(Color.pink);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        //find the source of the action
        if(event.getSource().equals(timer)){
            // records the current time event from timer
            double currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

            // finds the elapsed time from time and currentTime
            double elapsed = (double) ( currentTime - time) / 1000;

            //adds the extra to the elapsed time
            elapsed = elapsed + extra;

            //displays time in JLabel label
            label.setText(String.format("%.1f", elapsed));

        } else if (event.getSource().equals(start)){
            // the start button has been clicked
            if(!timer.isRunning()){
                time = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
                timer.start();
            }

        } else if (event.getSource().equals(stop)) {
            // the stop button has been clicked
            if(timer.isRunning()){
                //record current time in currentTime
                double currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                // finds the elapsed time from time and currentTime
                double elapsed = (double) ( currentTime - time ) / 1000;
                // (double) -> casts whatever is produced to be a double
                //adds the extra to the elapsed time
                elapsed = elapsed + extra;
                //stop the timer
                timer.stop();
            }
        } else{
            // the reset button has been clicked
            // stops the timer before resetting it
            if(timer.isRunning()){
                timer.stop();
            }
            // resets the timer
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            extra = 0;
            label.setText("00.00");
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class TimerPanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {
```

Well, you call your class  `TimerPanel` yet your extend a JFrame.

If the class is a "panel" then it should extend `JPanel`.

```
  TimerPanel panel = new TimerPanel();
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

You get the error because you can't add a JFrame to a JFrame.

> Any help with running my program, or any other improvements

Why are you trying to write the entire class before doing testing? Testing should be done step by step.

So you start by creating a frame and test that.

Then you add some components to the frame and test if the layout is correct.

Then you add ActionListeners to your buttons (one at a time) and test them.

That way when you have problems you know what you just changed.

Comment: Yes that solved the problem. Like I said, I am new to programming, so I will try to do it step by step in the future so I don't run into this problem again in the future!